# What is the meaning of "something is my pitch"?

Tags: meaning

I heard someone say

> "Something is my pitch".

Its sounds strange to me.

What is the meaning of "my pitch"?

Comment: Are you sure you heard it correct?

Comment: Perhaps the sentence was something like this : _"I enjoy talking to people on my pitch, you become an agony aunt."_ (http://www.bigissue.com/our-vendors/my-pitch)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a used in the sense of 'my idea' or 'my proposal' (which I'm trying to persuade you to go along with).

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/pitch)

> 4. [countable, usually singular] talk or arguments used by a person
>    trying to sell things or persuade people to do something
>
> *an aggressive sales pitch*
>
> *the candidate’s campaign pitch*
>
> *Each company was given ten minutes to make **its pitch**.*

I believe it's a baseball metaphor.

---

Also see the idioms [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/pitch)

> to make a determined effort to get something or to persuade somebody of something
>
> *He made a pitch to black voters in Alabama.*
>
> (British English, informal) to spoil somebody’s plans or their chances of getting something

(Oxford)